# passing asp.net control id to jquery function by parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

how can i pass asp.net control id dynamically to jquery function parameter?
here is how i am trying to do that

```
SelectedDivAnimation('#'+<%=txtFirstName.ClientID%>);
SelectedDivAnimation('#'+<%=txtLastName.ClientID%>);

 function SelectedDivAnimation(aspControl) {
        $(controlid).on('focus', function () {
            $(this).css({'width':'100%','transition':'1s'});
        });
        $(controlid).on('focusout', function () {
            $(this).css({ 'width': '50%', 'transition': '1s' });
        });
    }
```

i even try this

```
SelectedDivAnimation('#<%=txtFirstName.ClientID%>');
SelectedDivAnimation('#<%=txtLastName.ClientID%>');
```

when i run this it doesn't work as expected and nothing happens.

Comment: Are you able to provide a little more of the structure of your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything between `<%` and `%>` happens on the server so all you need to do is drop the `+` and move the second quote to after the `%>` -

```
SelectedDivAnimation('#<%=txtFirstName.ClientID%>');
SelectedDivAnimation('#<%=txtLastName.ClientID%>');
```

Assuming that it is in an ASP page.

So suppose that `txtFirstName.ClientID` is set to `client_a` the server will replace  `<%=txtFirstName.ClientID%>` with `client_a` before sending it to the client.  So the client will actually see this -

```
SelectedDivAnimation('#client_a');
```

If you are seeing the correct id's on your client then that's good, however you have another issue -

```
function SelectedDivAnimation(aspControl) {
    $(controlid).on('focus', function () {
        $(this).css({'width':'100%','transition':'1s'});
    });
    $(controlid).on('focusout', function () {
        $(this).css({ 'width': '50%', 'transition': '1s' });
    });
}
```

You pass the variable `aspControl` into your function however you are using a variable called `controlid`; you probably want to set them both to be the same, i.e. -

```
function SelectedDivAnimation(aspControl) {
    $(aspControl).on('focus', function () {
        $(this).css({'width':'100%','transition':'1s'});
    });
    $(aspControl).on('focusout', function () {
        $(this).css({ 'width': '50%', 'transition': '1s' });
    });
}
```

Comment: @JahanAhmedAbbasi Is your code in an asp page or js?

Comment: @JahanAhmedAbbasi see my expanded answer

Comment: on my aspx page i wrote a script in the head section and in document.ready method is call this SelectedDivAnimation() and pass a control id in parameter like var firstname=$('#<%=txtfirstname.clientid%>'); and than pass firstname in selectedDivAnimation(firstname) as parameter but it didn't work

Comment: thanks that solve the issue :) it was my silly mistake :)